# 2D Pixel Perfect platformer - the character and the ledges

Tags: xna, collision-detection

The character doesn't work very well because of the ledge.
Let's use some pics :

[image: Standing]
Here is the character in green, the light green is the spriteBox.
The black is for the "world".

At the bottom of the sprite, at 50% of the Texture Width, there is a Hot Spot. (at the center of the red cross)

I'm using this Hot Spot to detect collision from the bottom.
Everything works here.

[image: Running]
But if the player runs to the right and jump 1 pixel too late (too late means : when the Hot Spot isn't above a black pixel = `Texture.Width / 2 - 1` ), the player can't jump and will fall. Even if 50%-1px of his body touch the world. That's the problem.

[image: Landing]
Same problem for the landing.

[image: floating]

If I add more Hot Spots, here it will becomes : The character will float. So I don't know how to do...

Hope you will help.

Comment: You could add a condition when falling that adds another hotspot to the player instead, at say, point = x + (3/4)width (75%) and x + (1/4)width (25%). So add the hotspots only after a jump, and remove/ignore them after landing.

Comment: @Colton We should explore your idea in depth. It's a very good idea but there is at least one problem : When the character will land on a slope, he will land like on the pic 4.

Comment: Yeah, you are basically trying to have two different laws of physics, which is going to cause problems. One thought is, is your pixel character really going to be that big? If it was smaller, that little overlap would not be noticeable. For example, if the legs were closer together. A good option would be to focus on character design rather than programming in that case. (Which I see as an important factor to consider. Changing the design can make the programming a lot cleaner.) I will keep thinking on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at a similar game like worms, they have several hot spots as in your third example but they are staggered to match the sprite, they also change depending on the sprite used (eg facing left/right)

Have a read through the Worm2D page below:

[worms2d.info](http://worms2d.info/Worm_Walking)

Comment: Ho ! Very very interesting article even if I didn't find an answer, it helps me a lot. Thx !

Comment: I have found the answer in his link and with the help of Colton : I have to add Colton's 2 another hotspot plus I have to add a "marker" under the main hotspot (about 8px under it). If the "marker" isn't colliding the world, then I check the 2 hotspots added. If the marker collides the world, then I don't check them.
Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code sample of what I do:

```cs
public Boolean TouchingPlatformUpdater(Vector2 charapos){
    int[] BasePlatforms = { Convert.ToInt16(platformapos1.X), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos1.Y), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos2.X), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos2.Y), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos3.X), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos3.Y), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos4.X), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos4.Y), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos5.X), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos5.Y), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos6.X), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos6.Y), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos7.X), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos7.Y), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos8.X), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos8.Y), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos9.X), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos9.Y), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos10.X), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos10.Y), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos11.X), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos11.Y), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos12.X), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos12.Y), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos13.X), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos13.Y), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos14.X), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos14.Y), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos15.X), Convert.ToInt16(platformapos15.Y) };
    for (int Item = 0; Item < BasePlatforms.Length; Item = Item + 2) 
    {
        try
        {
            if (charapos.X > BasePlatforms[Item] - 15 && charapos.X < BasePlatforms[Item] + 60 && charapos.Y > BasePlatforms[Item + 1] - 14 && charapos.Y < BasePlatforms[Item + 1])
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
    return false;
```

My "player" is a square and so are the platforms, but you could do the same thing with the feet area and world on a finer level. What its doing is checking if the player is within the area covered by a single platform. You would have to find a way to make curves work however.

Overall, your system is pretty flawed. Just swap to my concept or find another one to use. The hotspot thing doesn't look like it will work too well. Id be able to fix yours for you though, but you didn't provide any code for us to help you fix. If you get code in this question, tell me at Zeusoflightning125@gmail.com and Ill edit my answer.

Comment: Your game is based on Tiles. Mine is based on PixelPerfect like the game `Worms` for example. This system works perfectly even with the slopes. The only problem is with the ledges like explained in this topic. I just want to know if someone has an idea, the code is really not needed. Thx anyway ! ^^